# Vue starts port 80 under mac and reports an error

Tags: vue.js

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPFmn.png)]

macos starts the vue project, and the port number is 80. It seems that the port below 1024 is disabled on the mac. How to solve this problem

I hope you can help me solve the problem of enabling the project with port 80 under mac

Comment: Is using a different port not an option, instead of fiddling with macOS security settings?

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when the **port is already in use**. You can solve this with two options.

- ##### Kill the port

1. Check if the port is already in use using this command `lsof -i :80`
2. Kill the port using the `PID` that will be provided if the port was in use using `kill {{PID}}`

   ---

- ##### Run the project on a different port

You can actually run your vue app on a different port

1. Using Npm -> `npm run serve --port 8080`
2. Using Yarn -> `yarn serve --port 8080`

Comment: No process occupies port 80, the mac system disables access below port 1024

Answer (score 0):

As your machine gets started, it will need to know the mapping of some hostnames to IP addresses before DNS can be referenced. This mapping is kept in the /etc/hosts file. In the absence of a name server, any network program on your system consults this file to determine the IP address that corresponds to a host name.

```
127.0.0.1           localhost       
127.0.0.1           yourdomain.com
```

Then you can run `npm run dev --host yourdomain.com` with custom host/port using vue-cli.

Also you can change the devServer in vue.config.js